# How to use the weights of a CNN being trained in a custom loss function in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I'm training a convolutional neural network (CNN) in Keras and I want to use the weights of the model in a custom loss function. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this because Keras doesn't allow direct access to the model weights in the loss function. Is there a way to use the weights of the CNN being trained in the custom loss function in Keras? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried many tricks like define a sub class of loss function and add the model as a class parameter but all i tried end up by the same error message: "RuntimeError: Cannot get value inside Tensorflow graph function." here my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import expit

def create_spreading_matrix(n_bits, n_cols):
    X = np.random.normal(0, 1, (n_bits, n_cols))
    X /= np.sqrt(np.sum(X**2, axis=1, keepdims=True))
    return X

watermark = "bob"
binary_string = ''.join(format(ord(c), '08b') for c in watermark)
binary_watermark = np.array([int(i) for i in list(binary_string)])
X = create_spreading_matrix(len(binary_string), 9)

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Initialize the loss as the classical cross-entropy loss
    loss = K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)

    # Get all the trainable weights in the model
    trainable_weights = model.trainable_weights

    # Check if the first convolutional layer is in the trainable weights
    if conv_layer_weights[0] in trainable_weights:
        # Add an additional term to the loss for the first convolutional layer
        conv_weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
        mean_weights = tf.reduce_mean(conv_weights, axis=3)
        flattened_weights = tf.reshape(mean_weights, shape=(-1,))
        flattened_weights_array = flattened_weights.numpy()
        Y = expit(np.dot(X, flattened_weights_array))
        r = - np.sum(binary_watermark * np.log(Y) + (1 - binary_watermark) * np.log(1 - Y))
        return loss + 0.1 * r
    return loss


# Load the MNIST dataset and split into training and testing sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# Normalize the pixel values to be between 0 and 1
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

# Reshape the input data to have a channel dimension (needed for convolutional layers)
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

# Define the model architecture
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    Dropout(0.25),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model with the custom loss function
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Get the trainable weights of the first convolutional layer
conv_layer_weights = model.layers[0].trainable_weights

# Train the model on the training data
model.fit(x_train, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train), epochs=1, batch_size=32,
          validation_data=(x_test, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)))

# Evaluate the model on the testing data
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(x_test, tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test))
print(f'Test accuracy: {test_acc}')
```